# Environment/Macros to command line for C make file

Tags: c, makefile, command-line, macros, environment-variables

Is it possible to substitute a macros, say `#define VAL 1`, with a command line argument, such as `VAL=1 make`? This was my approach, and I did not figure out how to change the make file. I was trying to add extra lines in `.all` in the Makefile, but nothing worked. So how to add a macros/environment from the command line?

Comment: Most C compilers take an option `-Dname=value` to define preprocessor symbols.

Comment: I tried in the beginning, both `-Dname=value make` and `make -Dname=value`  fail. Do i need to change the makefile?

Comment: `-D` needs to be passed to the compiler not `make`. Best done via the `CFLAGS` make var. So either change the makefile or do something like `make CFLAGS="-Dname=value"`. But be aware your makefile needs to be correctly written to use `CFLAGS`.

Comment: You have to either change the makefile, or find a _make variable_ in your makefile that you can override on the command line to add this argument.  Make is not a compiler, it doesn't know anything about compiler arguments or what should be done with them.  For example, if your makefile had a rule to run the compiler that included the make variable reference `$(CDEFINES)` in the compiler invocation, then you could run `make CDEFINES=-Dname=value` and it would work.

Comment: Okay, but how to add the CFLAGS in the make file, is it CFLAGS=""?